# Nested comments in mvc architecture

Tags: php, model-view-controller, comments

I am creating a website with MVC architecture and without framework. There are comments like in a blog. I would like to be possible to answer to a comment. But the answer functionnality does not work (when I wanna answer a comment, it is the same as a first comment) and I have difficulties finding why? Could you help me? Here is the adress of the website : cedricjager.com/stream

Here is connection.php:

```
class Connection {

// Connection
private function getBdd() {
try {
  $bdd = ConfigDB::database();
  $pdo = new PDO("mysql:host={$bdd['host']}; dbname={$bdd['db_name']}", "{$bdd['username']}", "{$bdd['password']}");
  $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
} catch (PDOException $e) {
  print "Error!: " . $e->getMessage() . "<br/>";
  die();
}
return $pdo;
}

// Query
public function query($sql, $params = array(), $fetch = null) {
try {
  $req = self::getBdd()->prepare($sql);
  $req->execute($params);

  if ($fetch == 'one') {
    return $req->fetch();
  } else if ($fetch == 'all') {
    return $req->fetchAll();
  } else {
    return $req;
  }

 } catch (PDOException $e) {
  print "Error!: " . $e->getMessage() . "<br/>";
  die();
 }
 }
```

Here is the model :

```
<?php
require_once 'Connection.php';

class Critics extends Connection{


//Récupère les critiques selon l'id de l'article.

public function findAllById($post_id) {
  $sql = "SELECT *, DATE_FORMAT(date, '%d/%m/%Y à %H:%i') AS date
          FROM critics
          WHERE id_movie = ?";
  $params = [$post_id];
  $comms = $this->query($sql,$params,'all');
  $critics_by_id = [];
  foreach ($comms as $comm) {
      $critics_by_id[$comm['id']] = $comm;
  }
  return $critics_by_id;
 }


//Récupèrer les critiques qui ont des enfants.

public function findAllWithChildren($post_id, $unset_children = true) {

$comms = $critics_by_id = $this->findAllById($post_id);
foreach ($comms as $id => $comm) {
    if ($comm['parent_id'] != 0) {
        $critics_by_id[$comm->parent_id]->children[] = $comm;
        if ($unset_children) {
            unset($comms[$id]);
        }
    }
}
return $comms;
}


//récupèrer une critique signalée.

public function findCritics() {

$sql = "SELECT *,DATE_FORMAT(date, '%d/%m/%Y à %H:%i') AS date FROM critics WHERE report=1";
$req = $this->query($sql);
return $req;
}

public function noCritic() {
 if ($this->findCritics() == false) {
    $msg = '<div class="alert alert-warning">Il n\'y a pas de critiques signalées.</div>';
    return $msg;
 }
 }


 //insérer une critique.
 public function insertCritic(){

  if(isset($_POST['content']) && !empty($_POST['content'])){

    $parent_id = isset($_POST['parent_id']) ? $_POST['parent_id'] : 0;
    $depth = 0;

    if ($parent_id != 0){

      $sql = 'SELECT id, depth  FROM critics WHERE  id = ?';
      $params = [$parent_id];
      $comm = $this->query($sql,$params, 'one');
      if ($comm == false) {
        throw new Exception("Ce parent n'existe pas");
      }
      $depth = $comm->depth + 1;
    }
     if ($depth >= 3) {
       echo "Impossible de rajouter une critique";
     }
     else {
       $sql = 'INSERT INTO critics SET content = ?, author = ?, id_movie = ?, parent_id = ?, date = NOW(), depth = ?';
       $params = array($_POST['content'], $_POST['nom'], $_GET['id'], $parent_id, $depth);
       $req = $this->query($sql,$params);
     }
   }
   }
  }
 }
```

Controller :

```
  public function single() {
  if (isset($_GET['id'])) {
  $id = $_GET['id'];
  $msg = $this->comment->reportCritic();
  $this->comment->insertCritic();
  $critics = $this->comment->findAllWithChildren($_GET['id']);
  $view = require 'Views/single.php';
  } else {
  header('Location:index.php?p=404');
  }
  }
```

Views

```
      <div class="sectioncomments" id="comments">
    <?php foreach($critics as $critic): ?>
        <?php require('comments.php'); ?>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
  </div>
  <hr>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-12">
      <div id="form-comment" class=" panel panel-default formComment">
        <div class="panel panel-heading">
          <h4>Poster une critique</h4>
          <br>
          <a href="#"><span class="return"></span></a>
        </div>
        <div class="panel panel-body">
          <form method="post"  class="form-group form-horizontal">
            <div class="form-group">
              <div class="col-sm-9">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="nom" placeholder="Votre nom..." name="nom">
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <div class="col-sm-9">
                <textarea class="form-control" id="content" placeholder="Votre critique..." name="content"></textarea>
              </div>
            </div>
            <p class="text-right"><button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Publier</button></p>
            <input type="hidden" name="parent_id" id="parent_id" value="0" >
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Comments.php

```
<div id="comment-<?= $critic['id'] ?>">
<p>
<b><?= $critic['author'] ?></b>
<span class="text-muted">le <?= $critic['date'] ?></span>
</p>
<div class="blockquote">
<blockquote>
  <?= htmlentities($critic['content']) ?>
</blockquote>
</div>
<div class="formulaire">
<form class="form-group"  method="post">
  <p class="text-left">
    <input type="hidden" name="valeur" value="<?= $critic['id_movie'] ?>">
    <input type="hidden" name="idval" value="<?= $critic['id'] ?>">
    <?php if($critic['depth'] <= 1): ?>
      <button  type="button" class="reply btn btn-default" data-id="<?= $critic['id'] ?>"><i class="fas fa-comments"></i></button>
    <?php endif; ?>
    <button type="submit" name="signal" class="btn btn-default"><i class="fas fa-bolt"></i></span></button>
  </p>
  </form>
  </div>
  </div>

 <div id="answer">
<?php if(isset($critic['children'])): ?>
    <?php foreach($critic['children'] as $critic): ?>
        <?php require('comments.php'); ?>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

First, I believe that you never set the `children` index mentionned in your 'comment.php' view :

```
<?php if(isset($critic['children'])): ?>
    <?php foreach($critic['children'] as $critic): ?>
        <?php require('comments.php'); ?>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Then you should not call two time in a row `findAllById` for perfomances purpose.

If I where you, maybe I fetch all One time and then build a tree based on what data you get from your query. It allow you to get an infinite nested comments capabilities. 
You can do it this way :

```
$critics = $this->getAllById($id);//movie id
$childs = []; //Will contain all childs indexed by parent_id
$index = []; //will contain all root critics (no parent)
foreach($critics as &$v){
     if($v['parent_id'] === 0){ //if no parent, then add to $index
          $indexes[$v['id']] = $v;
     } else{ //else create an array in $childs at index parent_id
         if(!isset($childs[$v['parent_id']])) $childs[$v['parent_id']] = [];
         $childs[$v['parent_id']][] = $v;
     }
}

//Then you can build your result : 
foreach($childs as $id=>&$child){
    $parent= $index[$id] ?? $child[$id] ?? null; // search for the parent of the current child
    if(is_null($parent)) continue; // a parent doesn't exists anymore, we ignor it, but you can throw an exception instead
    if(!isset($parent['children'])) $parent['children'] = [];
    $parent['children'][] = $child;
}
return $index;
```

Now critic should have a 'children' index where are listed all childs. It allow you to build a tree of comments without limit. 
All you have to keep in mind, is to correctly set the parent_id when post a new comment.

Let me know if it solves your problem.